# Safari border-color for text input

Tags: css, safari

I have a number of inputs of type text that I have placed a border and border-color around. They show up fine in Chrome, but in Safari the border is the color I selected on two sides and a basic blue on the other two sides. There is no problem with the border of a textfield I have in the same page. But a submit button does not have the correct border color either.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<label for="email">Email address</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />

<label for="telephone">Phone number</label>
<input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" />

<label for="notes">Notes</label>
<textarea type="textarea" id="notes" name="notes" /></textarea>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input, textarea, {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  padding: 4px 8px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-width: 2px !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #001b43;
  outline: none;
}
```

Searching around, I have found a few related problems and solutions and have tried them, but with no joy. For example:

```
input.text,
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=tel],
input[type=url],
input[type=search] {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I passed my question on to a friend. He figured it out quickly. The solution is:

```
border-style: solid;
```

Comment: 5 years a UI developer and I still didn't realize there were default values set per browser about this. Never thought that border would be something like `outset` or `inset` either. Good find!